# Merge FCM and Google OAuth GoogleServicesInfo.plist files

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have integrated `Google` frameworks(with `GoogleServicesInfo.plist`) for Google `OAuth` login with my project , later I had a requirement to implement `FCM push notifications`. So, in the same project I configured a `iOS` app in `FCM` console and downloaded the `GoogleServicesInfo.plist` file. Now both has dissimilar fields like client id, reverse client id, google App id, project id, etc. Only fields which are equal are Bundle id & ad unit id's.

So, my question here is,

1. Please advice what to do now to make both `OAuth` & `push notifications` work with a single `GoogleServicesInfo.plist` file.
2. How to merge those two files

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check this tutorial: https://medium.com/rocket-fuel/using-multiple-firebase-environments-in-ios-12b204cfa6c0

Comment: The link answers having two different files of different configuration. But my requirement is to have a single file for production with tow services plist files. Simply, I need both in production.